# How add method to Object that's already been created

Tags: javascript, methods

I have an array of objects that I'm building from JSON data. The JSON data I'm getting provides most of the necessary object properties, but I'd like to add some additional methods and properties to these objects. Adding the properties has been pretty simple for me. I'm simply doing:

```
searchResults[index].isVisible = true;
```

to add the isVisible property to each object. But I'd like to add a method to each object as well, maybe something like:

```
function toggleVisibility() {
    if (this.isVisible) {
        this.isVisible = false;
    } 
    else {
        this.isVisible = true;
    }  
}
```

So later in my code, I can do things like:

```
if (searchResults[x].isVisible) {
    // do things
}
```

So, not really sure how to add this method.

Comment: You do it the same way, but you assign a function. Functions are objects, you can pass them around, assign them to variables, etc...

Comment: That last little code snippet was probably a bad example on my part. I guess I'm looking more to do something like: searchResults[index].toggleVisiblity(). Oh, and this is in javascript, too, by the way, though you can probably tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the function like this

```
searchResults[index].toggleVisibility = function toggleVisibility() {
  return this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
};
```

See it work

```
var x = searchResults[index];
x.isVisible = true;

x.toggleVisibility();
console.log(x.isVisible); //=> false

x.toggleVisibility();
console.log(x.isVisible); //=> true
```

This does have implications, though. Typically when you have a lot of objects of the same type, methods like this are defined *once* on the object's prototype. Instead, you're defining a function on *each* object, and if you have a lot of objects, it could become memory intensive.

Here's another approach that only defines one function

```
function toggleVisibility(obj) {
  return obj.isVisible = !obj.isVisible;
}

var x = searchResults[index];
x.isVisible = true;

toggleVisibility(x);
console.log(x.isVisible); //=> false

toggleVisibility(x);
console.log(x.isVisible); //=> true
```

Comment: Shouldn't 'this' reference the global window object in this case and not the invoker?

Comment: @JohnIdol no, the function is defined on an object and when the function is called on that object, `this` will reference the object. Try the code above and see.

Comment: @JohnIdol it's no different than `var x = {foo: "bar"}; x.hello = function() { return this.foo; }; x.hello(); //=> "bar";`

Comment: Oh cool, so it would reference window only if the anonymous function wasn't defined on an object. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnIdol I didn't use an anonymous function anywhere.

Comment: Yes, this is for a phone app, so I definitely want to keep it small and light... This example makes sense and the use of the NOT operator is pretty slick. Never thought about using it that way. Only question on this is I notice the tendency to always assign the object to a variable. Is there any particular purpose for this? Why not just searchResults[index].isVisible = true.... and then toggleVisiblity(searchResults[index])?

Comment: @MikeP Happy to help. I just got tired of typing `searchResults[index]` over and over. `x` is just easier to read/write quickly. You can use `searchResults[index]` if you like.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a trillion! Just wanted to make sure...sometimes it's hard for me to wrap my head around how things are passed when it comes to arrays and objects... well not so much, but when you start of arrays full of objects, or objects of arrays, with objects in the arrays, etc. Anyway, thanks!